# Redirecting requests that would result in an HTTP 400 (Bad Request) error (Apache 2.2)

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, http, 400

Due to a security vulnerability in Wordpress, a bunch of my posts got renamed to something like:

`http://**MYSITE**/2008/08/21/**POSTNAME**/%&%28%7B$%7Beval%28base64_decode%28$_SERVER%5BHTTP_EXECCODE%5D%29%29%7D%7D%7C.+%29&%/`

I've since fixed the problem, upgraded Wordpress, and also upgraded my Web server to Apache 2.2.3.  The problem is, now I have a bunch of URLs that are indexed in Google and linked to from other sites.  Google will eventually remove them from their index, but in the meantime I want to rewrite the bad URLs to correct URLs.

I've tried the following mod_rewrite rule, but it doesn't seem to work.  It seems like Apache is seeing the request as "bad" and just returning an HTTP 400 error without ever consulting mod_rewrite (or mod_redirect).  Here's the rule I've tried:

`RewriteRule ^(20[0-9]{2}/[0-1][0-9]/[0-3][0-9]/[^/]+)/.*base64.*$ http://***MYSITE***/$1 [L,R=302,QSA]`

Which matches when I test it in a regular expression tool, but doesn't seem to make any difference to Apache.  Has anyone come across this problem?  Any possible solution?

Thanks!

Chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define a custom ErrorDocument for the 400 Errors like so:

```
ErrorDocument 400 /cgi-bin/handle400.cgi
```

and then have that cgi (or php or servlet or whatever) do the header rewriting and location redirecting.

EDIT: because of Jacek's answer I just tested above solution to confirm it works on Apache 2.2.

My Server Config:

```
ScriptAlias     /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"
ErrorDocument   400 /cgi-bin/handle400.pl
```

lukas$ cat /var/www/cgi-bin/handle400.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
while (my ($key, $val) = each %ENV) {
        print "$key = $val<BR>\n";
}
exit 0;
```

Now when accessing the broken URL that would produce an error 400 Bad Request before, I now get the following (partial) output:

```
...
REDIRECT_REQUEST_METHOD = GET
REDIRECT_STATUS = 400
REMOTE_ADDR = xx.xx.xx.xx
REQUEST_URI = /%&%28%7B$%7Beval%28base64_decode%28$_SERVER%5BHTTP_EXECCODE%5D%29%29%7D%7D%7C.+%29&%/
GATEWAY_INTERFACE = CGI/1.1
SCRIPT_URL = /cgi-bin/handle400.pl
...
```

So you do get enough information to do a proper status code change and location redirect.

Comment: Thanks!  I had tried this method, but somehow managed to not get it working.  I gave it another shot and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

'400 Bad request' means the request is so broken it cannot be parsed/understood by the server. That means the server has no data from the request (even the URL), so there is nothing mod_rewrite, or any other tool handling request data, can do about it.